# sub ranking rows with google sheet array-formulas

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, accounting, ranking-functions

i have a chart of accounts with multiple sub levels and i'm trying to get a dynamic serial number for table rows that depends on ranking and previous column , I've already used sheets formulas and i want to convert all formulas into array formulas [copy of my sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FuP5briu8h4HIkFuo24K11qEhoFJvKZpPKYt_m2iF0A/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: allow your sample to be editable, just share the link and allow all people with the link to be able to edit

Comment: and what did you do so far? please share with us your workout, code snippets, error logs, or any useful information to help answer your question. Good luck 

Comment: i can't figure out how to convert my formula into array formula

first formula to get grouped-ranking
`F2=IF(or(ROW(A2)=2,ISBLANK(A2)),0,
IF(A2=A1,F1,F1+1))`

second formula to get sub-ranking 
`K2=IF(or(ROW(A2)=2,ISBLANK(A2)),0,
IF(A2=A1,K1+1,1))`